# Oracle Text CONTAINS() query to return all rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

How can I write an Oracle text query (a `CONTAINS` query) that returns *all* rows in the index?

I've tried this:

```
select * from table t 
where contains(t.column, '%', 1) > 0
```

But this returns no rows.  Is there a pattern that will match *all* rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a query to match all rows you can simply short the comparison operator with a "1 = 1" predicate like this:

```
select * from table t where 1 > 0;
```

I usually have a case where a default search needs to return all rows, whereas a search with a keyword should check for rows using `contains`.

So, I use a `CASE` statement to conditionally search:

```
SELECT * FROM table t where 
(CASE WHEN :keyword IS NOT NULL THEN contains(t.column, :keyword, 1) 
ELSE 1 END) > 0;
```

Hope this helps!